# Метод run() не видит содержимое переменной из другого класса

Tags: java, многопоточность

В общем такая проблема: есть класс, в котором создаётся некоторая переменная, думаю его здесь писать не придётся... В эту переменную пользователь записывает IP для использования Socket, который находится в другом классе. Фишка в том, что я уже всё десять раз проверил, и понял, что методу run(), в котором собственно и находится Socket, вообще наплевать, где лежит переменная. Если она вне него, то он не видит её содержимое. Её видит, а её содержимое - нет!!1!!!

```
public class Client implements Runnable, Initializable {
private static Main m = new Main();
static private Socket connection;
static private ObjectInputStream input;
static private ObjectOutputStream output;

public void run() {
    try {
        while(true){
            connection = new Socket(InetAddress.getByName(m.s), 3111);
            output = new ObjectOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
            input = new ObjectInputStream(connection.getInputStream());
            output.writeObject("Working");
            System.out.println(input.readObject());
            System.out.println(m.s);
        }
    } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private static void sendData(Object obj){
    try {
        output.flush();
        output.writeObject(obj);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Собственно, класс Main и есть тот первый класс. А s - переменная типа String.
К слову, даже сканер, находясь в методе run(), не может читать какие-либо текстовые файлы.
Я знаю, что это нытьё, но я уже третью неделю с этой фигнёй сижу... помогите, умоляю...

Comment: Стоит почитать про JMM. Этот метод работает в отдельном потоке, а без синхронизации _видимость_ неволотильных переменных между потоками не гарантируется.

Comment: Передавайте s как параметр конструктора. В итоге, ждете ввод адреса, при его получении создаете экземпляр Client с передачей ему адреса, и запускаете поток.

Comment: общие переменные, используемые в разных потках без синхронизации - абсолютное зло. Вам повезло, что ваш код сразу не стал работать. Он мог бы сначала работать, а потом, в продакшене, накрыться.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте перед переменной модификатор volatile. Операции чтения/записи volatile переменной являются атомарными. Результат операции записи значения в volatile переменную одним потоком, становится виден всем другим потокам, которые используют эту переменную для чтения из нее значения.

И почитайте здесь https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/atomic.html

Comment: Увы, модификатор volatile не помог

Comment: где можно посмотреть ваш код?

Comment: Одну секундочку

Comment: В общем, помимо моих отсталых навыков программирования, со способностями быстро осваивать интернет у меня тоже немало проблем. Заранее извиняюсь за свой код, я ещё далёк от истины понимания...

Comment: https://bitbucket.org/skakunovnick/helpmepls/get/3973e2e54f3f.zip

Comment: Пишите, если можете помочь сюда skakunov.nick2016@yandex.ru

Comment: Внес изменения в Main и Client у вас в bitbucket, но проверить не могу. Для верности нужен весь проект, чтоб запускался. Проверьте